# Linux How to find the id of a user who ran some particular command using sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, audit

In shared environment where multiple users have sudo account, I want to find out underlying user id (not a sudo account) details who has invoked particular script. Thanks.

I tried below but it does not fulfill my requirement : echo $USERNAME gives me sudo account details but I am looking for login id

Comment: `ps -p $(ps -C script.sh -o ppid=) -o ruser=`

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` sets the `SUDO_USER` environment variable to a username corresponding to the real user id of the process that executed it, so that will typically be the username of the user who invoked `sudo`.

It also sets the `USER` environment variable to the target user:

```
$ id -un
chazelas
$ sudo printenv SUDO_USER USER
chazelas
root
```

So within a script invoked as `sudo the-script`, you can find the original user name in `$SUDO_USER`.

And on Linux, you can find that information for a given process by looking into `/proc/<pid>/environ`:

```
$ sudo sleep 3m &
[1] 97380
$ sudo grep -z '^SUDO_USER=' /proc/[1-9]*/environ | tr '\0' '\n'
/proc/97382/environ:SUDO_USER=chazelas
$ ps -fp 97382
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root       97382   97381  0 12:40 pts/8    00:00:00 sleep 3m
```

In some configurations including mine above, `sudo` will run the target command in a child process and hang around waiting for its termination instead of running it in the same process. You can determine the user who invoked that `sudo` command from the real user id of the process:

```
$ ps -o ruser= -p 97380
chazelas
```

Answer (score 0):

View the entire chain of possible user changes:

```bash
pstree -sul $(ps -C script.sh -o pid=)
```

`-s` *show parents.*
`-u` *uid changes.*